# Check if more than one element :contains certain text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a function to fire only if more than one element in a div contains a certain text. I've tried the following approach, but cant seem to make it work:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h2> Some text here </h2>
    <p> Some text here too </p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready.(function(){
    $('h2 && p:contains("text")'). //Do something ();

});
```

In this case the code should "Do something", because both h2 and p contain "text".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the number of elements is more than 1 with `length` like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('div *:contains("text")').length > 1){ 
    $('div').css('background','red')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2> Some text here </h2>
  <p>Some text here too</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It would failed if there is two divs with which one containing one element containing 'text'. http://jsfiddle.net/4HQc4/1456/

Comment: @A.Wolff that's right but that situation isn't part of the question itself; anyway the logic here will apply for any particular case with a little change ... for example the one you pointed https://jsfiddle.net/mfgzx7mr/

Comment: Ya but then you should use: `$('> *:contains("text")', this)` otherwise it could still be confusing  https://jsfiddle.net/mfgzx7mr/1/ or more relevant https://jsfiddle.net/mfgzx7mr/2/

Comment: Thank guys! This approached worked for me, combining it with A. Wolff observation that $('> *:contains("text")', this) will work when there is more than one div!

Answer (score 0):

You can even write this:

```
$('h2:contains("text")').length + $('p:contains("text")').length === 2
```

This way you will sure that both h2 and p are matched